# assigning values to datagrid cells using loop

Tags: c#, list

I would like to assign cells in a datagrid some values (some columns)
using

```
foreach(var member in listofmember)
{
   ///what method is possible
}
```

listofmember is a list of structs. I would only like to display some of the struct's members in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an ItemSource is better for handling such situations, e.g your DataGrid contains `Person` class information so you could assign it to the list of Person:

```
myDataGrid.ItemSource = new List<Person>{p1,p2,p3};
```

Also you could simply search on your list and do change on it, finally reassign it to your grid. in this way you could separate them also you could use NotifyPropertyChange in future.